# Using `__await` to await a TPL task in C++/Cli

Tags: .net, visual-studio, async-await, c++-cli

I found out I can use the keywords `__resumable` and `__await` in Visual Studio 2015 to do something very similar to C#'s `async`/`await` in C++.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to use `__await` for TPL tasks in C++/Cli?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 main obstacles:

1. If you try to include the ppl headers in a project compiled with /clr you will get an error as there are some C++ headers which are still prohibited for use in a C++-CLI project. Those include `<mutex>` `<condition_variable>` and `<future>` for instance (though `<mutex>` seems to be ok for Visual Studio 2019).
   I overcame this limitation by implementing my own library using the raw WinAPI contructs. but that is a bit extreme I guess. Alternatively you can forward declare all prohibited types (but you'll have to use another level of indirection everywhere)
2. In order to use `await` / `co_await` the C++ module must be compiled with the /await flag which is not allowed with the /clr flag.
3. The return type of a function that calls `co_await` must implement a certain **concept** (basically, a set of functions the compiler calls internally when you use `co_await`). You can't use void return value as you would in C# for instance and other managed return values won't make sense.

The only thing I found to work (once I overcame limitation 1) was to translate the native awaitable type (your own implemented future / task) to a managed `Task^` which can be awaited in C# code.

```
template <typename NativeResultPolicy, typename NativeCallableT, typename... Args>
Task<typename NativeResultPolicy::ManagedResultT>^
    MethodAsTask(NativeCallableT nativeMethod, typename ClassOf<decltype(nativeMethod)>::type* self, Args&&... args)
{
   // prepare a completion source and invoke native method
   gcroot<TaskCompletionSource<NativeResultPolicy::ManagedResultT>^> taskCompletionSrc= gcnew TaskCompletionSource<NativeResultPolicy::ManagedResultT>();    
    (*self.*nativeMethod)(std::forward<Args>(args)...).then(
        [taskCompletionSrc](NThreading::srfuture<typename NativeResultPolicy::NativeResultT> fut)
    {
        // once future is ready, translate its contained value / exception to a managed value / exception using the supplied policy.
        NativeResultPolicy::SetCompletionSource(taskCompletionSrc, fut);
    }
    );
    // return a Task^ that can be awaited
    return completionTask->Task;
}
```

The translation function above invokes a method that returns a native task-like object, and uses `::then` with a lambda expression to set the value for the TaskCompletionSource once the task is ready.

The NativeResultPolicy type is a simple type with a method that does the actual translation. here is an example:

```
class CompletionPolicy
{
public:
    using NativeResultT = typename void;
    using ManagedResultT = bool;

    static void SetCompletionSource(TaskCompletionSource<ManagedResultT>^ completionResult, future_t<NativeResultT>& fut)
    {
        try
        {
            fut.get();
            completionResult->SetResult(static_cast<bool>(true));
        }
        catch (const std::exception& err)
        {
            completionResult->SetException(gcnew System::IO::IOException(gcnew System::String(err.what())));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Nina. Interesting solution. I had to read it a couple of times but I think I understand now whats going on. You are translating a future into a TPL task in order to consume it as awaitable in C#. E.g. you want to use a C++/Cli module in a C# project. I was trying to accomplish the exact opposite thing: How can I consume an awaitable Task (from a C# library) in a C++ project. As I asked this question 3 years ago there was no coroutines in any C++ compilers. But since you said the /await flag is incompatible with /clr coroutines couldn't help me anyway, right?

Comment: Right. async / await are simply not supported in c++-cli. that means that you have to implement everything using raw callbacks.

Comment: Which, If i remember correctly, is also quite painful since C++ lambdas are incompatible with .NET delegates.

Comment: Correct. I think the whole purpose of c++-cli is to expose native functionality to high level managed code, not the other way around.

Comment: I would disagree on that one. Types like `Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsControl` or `System::Windows::Interop::HwndSource` enable people to embed Winforms or WPF controls into Win32/C++ applications. From there it is only a small step to linking all kind of .NET libraries to those applications. And for the most part its working splendidly. It just looks like C++/Cli has it's best days behind it.